# XML to SQL 2008r2 issue

Tags: sql, xml

For some reason I cannot distinguish, when I run the code shown below, instead of giving me the correct "DE" value, it repeats the first value of "00".  This only happens in the last column.  Any ideas where I have gone wrong?

```
USE EDIXML
GO
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML
SELECT  code,type,name,DE
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'TRN-862/SEG-BSS/DE')
WITH 
(
code [varchar](100) '@code',
type [varchar](100) '@type',
name [varchar](100) '@name',
DE [varchar](100) '../DE'
)
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Below is the XML data:

```
<TRN-862>
  <SEG-BSS>
    <SEG-INFO code="BSS" name="BEGINNING SEGMENT FOR SHIPPING SCHEDULE" />
    <DE code="0353" name="TRANSACTION SET PURPOSE CODE" type="ID" desc="Original">00</DE>
    <DE code="0127" name="REFERENCE IDENTIFICATION" type="AN">512</DE>
    <DE code="0373" name="DATE" type="DT">20160204</DE>
    <DE code="0675" name="SCHEDULE TYPE QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Shipment Based">SH</DE>
    <DE code="0373" name="DATE" type="DT">20160204</DE>
    <DE code="0373" name="DATE" type="DT">20160227</DE>
    <DE code="0328" name="RELEASE NUMBER" type="AN">512</DE>
    <DE code="0127" name="REFERENCE IDENTIFICATION" type="AN" />
    <DE code="0367" name="CONTRACT NUMBER" type="AN" />
    <DE code="0324" name="PURCHASE ORDER NUMBER" type="AN" />
    <DE code="0676" name="SCHEDULE QUANTITY QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Actual Discrete Quantities">A</DE>
  </SEG-BSS>
```

And finally, below is what the query delivers:

```
code    type    name    DE
0353    ID  TRANSACTION SET PURPOSE CODE    00
0127    AN  REFERENCE IDENTIFICATION    00
0373    DT  DATE    00
0675    ID  SCHEDULE TYPE QUALIFIER 00
0373    DT  DATE    00
0373    DT  DATE    00
0328    AN  RELEASE NUMBER  00
0127    AN  REFERENCE IDENTIFICATION    00
0367    AN  CONTRACT NUMBER 00
0324    AN  PURCHASE ORDER NUMBER   00
0676    ID  SCHEDULE QUANTITY QUALIFIER 00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument
     @hDoc OUTPUT,
     @XML;
SELECT code,
       type,
       name,
       DE
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'TRN-862/SEG-BSS/DE') 
WITH(
code [VARCHAR](100) '@code', 
type [VARCHAR](100) '@type', 
name [VARCHAR](100) '@name', 
DE [VARCHAR](100) '.'
)
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank  you so so much!

Answer (score 1):

OPENXML is outdated. You should use the "real" XML methods like this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<TRN-862>
  <SEG-BSS>
    <SEG-INFO code="BSS" name="BEGINNING SEGMENT FOR SHIPPING SCHEDULE" />
    <DE code="0353" name="TRANSACTION SET PURPOSE CODE" type="ID" desc="Original">00</DE>
    <DE code="0127" name="REFERENCE IDENTIFICATION" type="AN">512</DE>
    <DE code="0373" name="DATE" type="DT">20160204</DE>
    <DE code="0675" name="SCHEDULE TYPE QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Shipment Based">SH</DE>
    <DE code="0373" name="DATE" type="DT">20160204</DE>
    <DE code="0373" name="DATE" type="DT">20160227</DE>
    <DE code="0328" name="RELEASE NUMBER" type="AN">512</DE>
    <DE code="0127" name="REFERENCE IDENTIFICATION" type="AN" />
    <DE code="0367" name="CONTRACT NUMBER" type="AN" />
    <DE code="0324" name="PURCHASE ORDER NUMBER" type="AN" />
    <DE code="0676" name="SCHEDULE QUANTITY QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Actual Discrete Quantities">A</DE>
  </SEG-BSS>
</TRN-862>';

  SELECT DE.value('@code','varchar(max)') AS code
        ,DE.value('@type','varchar(max)') AS type
        ,DE.value('@name','varchar(max)') AS name
        ,DE.value('.','varchar(max)') AS DE
  FROM @xml.nodes('/TRN-862/SEG-BSS/DE') AS One(DE)
```

The result

```
code    type    name                            DE
0353    ID      TRANSACTION SET PURPOSE CODE    00
0127    AN      REFERENCE IDENTIFICATION        512
0373    DT      DATE                            20160204
0675    ID      SCHEDULE TYPE QUALIFIER         SH
0373    DT      DATE                            20160204
0373    DT      DATE                            20160227
0328    AN      RELEASE NUMBER                  512
0127    AN      REFERENCE IDENTIFICATION    
0367    AN      CONTRACT NUMBER 
0324    AN      PURCHASE ORDER NUMBER   
0676    ID      SCHEDULE QUANTITY QUALIFIER     A
```